# Module.exports returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to export a variable from a file, but when I require it in another I get undefined. I suspect my functions are causing it, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Index.js:

```
app.post("/", (req,res) =>{ 
    console.log("Get from /");
    module.exports.SimpleMessage = 'Hello world';                 //exporting variable
    exec('npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
            }
        });
    res.send("Server received the request");
                            });

// starting the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

Deploy.js:

```
async function main() {
    const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");
 
    var msg = require('../src/index.js');                              //requiring variable
    console.log(msg.SimpleMessage);           

    const hello_world = await HelloWorld.deploy();   
 }
```

(Edit) This is the whole Deploy.js function:

```
async function main() {
    const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");
 
    var msg = require('../src/index.js');                              //requiring variable
    console.log(msg.SimpleMessage);           

    const hello_world = await HelloWorld.deploy();   
 }
 
 main()
   .then(() => process.exit(0))
   .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
     process.exit(1);
   });
```

Comment: I guess your `main` function runs before any post request is submitted to your application, and hence before anything gets exported by the other module. You could move `module.exports.SimpleMessage = 'Hello world';` out of the post handler into the top level.

Comment: @GOTO0 Thanks for you answer. It works if I do what you wrote, but I want the value of that variable to be what I get in the post request. Is there any way to fix it without moving the line? I posted the whole Deploy.js file, if you could check if there is anything to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so there are a few things to unwrap over here:

- your `require()` is probably invoked before `module.exports.SimpleMessage = 'Hello world';`  - an easy issue to encounter when you deal with async functions
- `require()` is implemented in such a way that if you call it twice with the same file, the second time around only the cached value is returned and so, if the value of `SimpleMessage` changes, you will not be able to import it any more. Instead only the original value will be returned.

A quick and simple solution is to export a value that will not change instead, like a function

```js
let SimpleMessage;

module.exports.getSimpleMessage = () => SimpleMessage;

app.post("/", (req,res) =>{ 
    console.log("Get from /");
    SimpleMessage = 'Hello world';

    // and the rest of your logic
});
```

at this point you can reference `getSimpleMessage` that will be cached by `require()` but still will always return the updated version of `SimpleMessage`

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thank you. Could you just help me with accessing it in deploy.js. I added "const { getSimpleMessage } = require("../src/index")". Do I get the value like this: var SimpleMessage = getSimpleMessage()?

Comment: yeah. Except that you should avoid using `var` and use `const` or `let` instead. `var` is a relic of the past and has a very unintuitive behaviour

Comment: Do you maybe know why adding  "const { getSimpleMessage } = require("../src/index")" causes an error when I want to deploy? Command failed: npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Comment: the error is self-explanatory. It's not related to the code (unless your code starts the server twice). You probably already have another process running on port 3000. Perhaps you forgot to kill  your app after starting it previously?

Comment: Everything works fine (is deployed) if I remove the require. That's why I'm confused. I'm running the index.js server on port 3000.

Comment: then perhaps you are starting the server twice? Perhaps you have some recursive imports? file a imports file b that imports file a? importing "index.js" can be tricky. Depending on how you structure your project you may be importing it automatically without even realising it. I cannot answer that question without seeing the whole app though. In your current example I don't even see how you start your server. One way to check that would be to run it with a debugger and check how many times you actually start a server or to put a console.log('starting') just before starting the server

Comment: I'll look into it. I start the server with just a simple app.listen(3000, () => ... . Thanks again for everything.

Comment: join me in the real time chat and we can figure it out together https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246636/module-exports-returns-undefined

Comment: back from lunch and I'm back in the chat and I think I now fully understand your problem